# Compiling Node 0.4.7 on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, ssl, express

I'm trying to compile 0.4.7 for Heroku support, but I can't seem to get ssl support working, which express requires.

I've installed `libssl-dev`, and even tried to install openssl by hand, but nothing seems to get this working. What do I need to do to get node running?

```
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/skendall/node/node-v0.4.7/build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): 
    {task: cxx node_crypto.cc -> node_crypto_4.o}
```

Comment: lol, I had the exactly same problem last night on Ubuntu 11.10, for the exact same reasons. Everything else worked: 0.4.12, 0.6.5, 0.6.7

Comment: @alessioalex: I found an article that indicated it was possible to change the node version on your heroku instance by creating some sort of bundle. It looked pretty elaborate and complicated, but this may be the right way to go.

Comment: Yup I also read that, but was still wondering what's with Node 0.4.7 :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use v0.4.9 will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To get node-v0.4.7, or any other version before node-v0.4.12, working with ubuntu 11.10 will involve modifying the source code of node.

Specifically src/node_crypto.cc, which requires the removal of checks for any ssl methods other than sslv1. this section is roughly located around line 100 in the file.
Once done, follow the usual: ./configure; make; make install

This change was tested and worked with express lib, on ubuntu 11.10 with openssl compiled without sslv2.